# How to start develop application for fire os in android studio IDE

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, amazon-fire-tv

I am going to start develop application for fire TV i can create an application using Eclipse successfully, But when i try the same procedure to create new application which compile with Firetv SDK got some Gradle error on android studio.. i am stuck with this issues for around one week. 
The error is  `Gradle app neame project refresh failed:
           Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.
           Gradle settings`

I searched lot about this error in google but cant get  any solution
Sorry for my bad English.

My even log says:

Gradle 'Test' project refresh failed:
           Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.
           Gradle settings
My build  gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 17
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your build.gradle file?  Also, could you post more of the log output for this error?  The more detail you can provide the easier it is to identify the problem.  Thank-you.

Comment: @AndroidGuy  i have added the information above . I just create new application which compile with fire tv sdk not working but if i create same application with compile api 17 mean it works ... so my problem is in fire tv sdk.

Answer (score 6):

My case, delete `~/.gradle/` and suddenly all working well again.

good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Invalidate Caches And Restart Also Works. Try It Out By Going 
To File and selecting Invalidate caches and restart

Comment: is this answer incomplete? Seems to stop prematurely.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to Android Studio -> File -> Close project. After closing the project,reopen it afresh. This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I couldn't understand about ~/.gradle/ folder... but now I got it
and solved! delete here folder!