# Android studio unexpected lock file protocol

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Am trying to import an android studio project into a new machine. The import goes on fine and the directories of the project are displayed correctly.However, when i try to build or clean the project, android studio raises the following error

```
Gradle 'ngoma' project refresh failed
Error:Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.
```

I have tried closing and reopening the project, changing the permissions of the folder containing the projects but nothing is changing. How can I solve this error??

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23196254/how-to-start-develop-application-for-fire-os-in-android-studio-ide

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error:Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31743942/errorunexpected-lock-protocol-found-in-lock-file-expected-3-found-0)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Go into your local file project and search for the ".gradle" folder

Erase it and restart your IDE.

Comment: Worked for me! nice and easy :)

Comment: For me, I delete `~/.gradle/caches/2.8/`, then it works. (2.8 is gradle version that used in the project). In my situation, it's a fresh project without a ".gradle" folder in project root directory, so you may delete project-level ".gradle" folder as well.

Answer (score 5):

Removing the contents from .gradle folder in **home** folder and restarting Android Studio resolved the issue. Please note I earlier removed  the  contents from .gradle folder from Android Project folder, but this did not help.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and deleting the project's .gradle folder didn't fix the problem.

I solved the problem by deleting the `C:\Users\<username>\.gradle` folder and restarting my IDE.

Answer (score 1):

The SDK library is no specified, try to set it on configuration

Answer (score 1):

I've tried several solution:

- **First Solution:** Go to <kbd>File</kbd> -> <kbd>Invalid Caches</kbd>, Restart.
- **Second Solution:** First, <kbd>Build</kbd> -> <kbd>Clean Project</kbd> and then <kbd>Build</kbd> -> <kbd>Rebuild Project</kbd>
- **Third Solution:** First, close the project and remove from workspace of Android Studio, then go to `C:\Users\user\.gradle` then delete `.gradle` folder. After that, open the project again.

But none of these worked. Then I found a solution. In my case, the problem was with the Gradle version. Check your Gradle version in <kbd>File</kbd> -> <kbd>Project Structure</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) and the Plugin version as well:

[image: In my case, the problem was in gradle version. Check your Gradle version File -> Project Structure(Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S) and Plugin version also.]

Answer (score 0):

i fixed my issue by invalidating caches, go to file -> invalidate caches / restart

Answer (score -1):

It is also enough to delete only all *.lock files in ~/.gradle folder