# Error:Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

After upgrading Android Studio to 1.3, I can't compile my project anymore. I am getting `Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.`. I have tried with deleting my `.gradle` folder but that does not solve the problem. Anything else I can do?

Comment: if you do anything steps, solution but not work, try delete all file on scripts folder, 
 (.gradle/caches/<gradle-version-like-6.5>/scripts/)

Answer (score 87):

I have solved it by deleting the folder

> c: \ users \ [myusername] \ .gradle \ caches \ 2.14.1

After reopening Android studio it was all fine

Comment: I wasn't sure which gradle version my project was using. It's in File -> Project structure -> Project (per Android Studio 2.1.3)

Comment: Thank you so much @RaulPinto for this crucial piece of information.

Comment: That was old eclipse project imported. After arranging build sdk and target sdk to last within  build gradle I got this error. Then I just  pressed 'clean project' and the error was gone after plain 'build apk'

Comment: Fix still working under Android Studio 3.4.2. Clean did not work, invalidate Caches & Restart did not work. I deleted all folders in cache so downloading took some minutes after restart.

Comment: does not really help,  I have remove the content of   root@nusik-ryzen:/root/.gradle/caches# rm -rf *

Comment: Or rename the gradle version folder to i.e. (for me) to 5.6.1_old. Restart AS and reopen your project. The gradle caches will be rebuilt.

My project was obscured by a BSOD in the middle of a gradle rebuild.

Answer (score 49):

okay here's very lightweight solution with steps:

- **Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S**  or **File->Project Structure**
- **Select Project** from left panel
- Now check your **Gradle Version** at right panel
- In my case my **Gradle Version** is **3.3**
- Navigate **C:\Users\ashish\.gradle\caches** and delete your **Gradle Version** - **3.3** named folder.
- Now **restart** or **open your project** again from workspace.

Greetings...your problem is solved.

Comment: a very underrated full proof  method. Thank you @Ashish

Answer (score 23):

Go into your local file project and search for the ".gradle" folder

Erase it and restart your IDE

Answer (score 22):

You must erase **/.gradle** folder from user directory, **not from project**, it`s a hidden directory, if you used linux-based system it is in /home/user/.gradle and press "alt"+"." to show hidden folders

Comment: can you please help me,I couldnot find the .gardle folder,alt+. is not working either

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: not working for me is delete this folder ".gradle" also do "invalidate cache/Restart" but not working can you please help me

Comment: in ubuntu .gradle is hidden, you can see it in list with command "ls -a", to delete it close android studio and run "sudo rm -rf .gradle" in your home.

Answer (score 21):

Deleting cache folder take long time because it have more than 200k files which is more than 3GB. There is quick view as Ashish mentioned.

I also faced this error in only one app.

**Go through the step.**

1. In you project open `gradle-wrapper.properties` file. Which is located in Gradle Script in Android structure. As shown in below image.

   [image]
2. In that file check `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip`. Here gradle version is 4.6.

[image]

3.So all cache for that project will be store in your `C:\Users\Your PC Name or User Name\.gradle\caches\4.6`. As shown in below image.

[image]

4. Close your android studio and delete the 4.6 folder. After deletion open android studio.

That's all. It took mine 6 hours to figure out and deleting cache folder. So I decide to post this answer. So people will not waste same time.

Comment: But Could be the root cause of this problem

Comment: I think cache files are corrupt that why we need to delete them.

Comment: Okay so the cache files are corrupted that we have a established but can cause a cache file to be corrupted

Comment: Don't have an idea.

Comment: @Charles for me when my computer crashed while Android Studio was building made the cache file to be corrupted

Comment: @juancamilo87 Same here

Answer (score 11):

```
Delete C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches folder and restart the project.
```

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem.
And deleting the project's .gradle folder didn't fix the problem.

I solved the problem by deleting the `C:\Users\<username>\.gradle` folder and made studio refresh the entire gradle build.  I found I had 4 different versions of gradle installed from my upgrade path.

Answer (score 9):

In android studio, Click on the "Invalidate caches/Restart.." and confirm.

Comment: This didn't solve my problem. In-fact, now my IDE wont start at all!

Answer (score 6):

This happened after my computer froze and I had to force it to restart. To fix it, I ran this and then everything worked. No Android Studio restart required:

```sh
cd path/to/.gradle/
find . -name "*.lock" -delete
```

Comment: Couldn't fine the .gradle folder navigating directories, but i was able to get to this directory via the terminal. Ran the find and delete command and it works now. Thanks!

Comment: This is what worked for me too thanks, however I did not use command line , I used a windows app called `Everything` searched for `.lock C:\Users\USER\.gradle\ !C:\Users\USER\.gradle\caches_old` then select all delete

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same problem in Android Studio 4.0.1 when my computer froze and I had to force shut down.

What I did to resolve the issue was delete **.gradle** folder from the project directory and build the project again.

1. Open the **Project** pane, if not open already.
2. Select the Project view (not Android) from the drop-down menu
3. The first folder (in red colour) will be **.gradle**, Right Click > Delete.
4. Build the project again.

[image]

Comment: Deleting .gradle folder inside the project instead of C: solve my issue, thanks

Answer (score 4):

From File menu click on Invalidate Cache / Restart. And then Click on Invalidate and Restart. It will fix your problem.

[image: Invalidate Caches]

Comment: simple and effective solution. Thanks @Jakir

Comment: But i am facing this problem regularly for the same project. almost daily when i open the project it happens, why is that so?

Comment: Not sure. Try to re locate the project. You  can also try to delete all dot (.) folders and re import the project to Android studio. (Keep backup before do that)

Answer (score 3):

All of these solutions did not work for me on Android Studio 2.1. What worked was me opening gradle-wrapper.properties in project folder and changing my gradle reference on the line below:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

This was changed to:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.13-all.zip
```

After which gradle upgraded and the app started working!

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to delete all your gradle files. Your just need to delete `C:\Users\(your user name)\.gradle\daemon\(gradle version)\registry.bin.lock` and you are done!

Answer (score 1):

None of the above worked for me ....

You just need to go to File -> Project Structure or jus press **Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S**

and then on the top left click **Project** Make sure that your **Android Plugin Version** is the same as you **Android Studio Version** .. This should fix it

additionally

You can also create a new Project and check under Project view initially you'll be in Android .. change the view to ... Project - > gradle (Note .. not .gradle only gradle ) ->wrapper ->gradle-wrapper properties.. open this file and you can see the last line ie ..

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

make sure you have the same gradle version in your old files as well

Check out this Youtube Video i made regarding this issue

https://youtu.be/-Ngn4YvbKtw

Answer (score 1):

We successfully resolved this error.. 
Go to your project location in my case it was F:=> PROJECT NAME=> .gradle.. and we deleted the the .gradle file.. then restarted android studio and loaded the project again.. and this time the the gradle build successfully.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, GRADLE_USER_HOME was not set due to a machine change. After re-setting this env variable, everything works fine again.

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions here worked for me.
For anyone who might run into my situation, here's what worked for me:

In addition to the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44858809/7779576), I also

1. Deleted `~/.gradle/daemon/[GRADLE_VERSION]`
2. Deleted `~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-[GRADLE_VERSION]-all`
3. Deleted `[PROJECT_PATH]/.gradle`

Restarted Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

1. Get into the `.gradle` folder in the root of the project.
2. There, you might see a couple of versions. Pick the gradle version that you're using in the porject.
3. cd into `taskArtifacts` folder.
4. clear the `cache.properties.lock` file.

Finally, build the project. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above resolutions worked for my instance of this error. I had just started the project, so I really wasn't concerned about the loss of it. I completed the following:

1. Selected "File\Close Project" and the project closed.
2. The opening screen to create a new project came up.
3. I deleted the project from the list just to have it not show in the list.
4. Created a new project with a slightly different name.
5. Ran the new project and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

-
Go into your local file project and search for the ".gradle" folder,(**folder from user directory**, **not from project**, it`s a hidden directory, if you used linux-based system it is in /home/user/.gradle and press "alt"+"." to show hidden folders,)

- Erase it and restart your IDE

if this doesnt work then,
All of these solutions did not work for me on Android Studio 2.1. What worked was me opening gradle-wrapper.properties in project folder and changing my gradle reference on the line below:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

This was changed to:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.13-all.zip
```

After which gradle upgraded and the app started working!

Answer (score 0):

Open your previous project and open file>ProjectStructure>project
check this gradle version,android plugin version of previous project 
and set it to your current project .and click invalidate/restart

Answer (score 0):

For the persons who have this problem on <**Android Studio 3.1.2**>.
After I got this problem, I done all solutions in this topic. But each of the solutions alone did not solve my problem.
So I've combined some strategies.

---

1. First I removed application from Android Studio Launcher List.
2. Second I deleted all the content from .gradle (**FOLDER FROM USER
   DIRECTORY**).
3. Third I import the project again (**after sync i got the error
   again**).
4. Fourth while project is open I used <**Invalidate Cache / Restart**>
   option from **FILE menu**.

---

I hope this solution work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `.gradle` directory from the user directory is not enough. Make sure to delete the `.gradle` directory from the project directory as well. In fact I would start with the project and only if that isn't enough should you delete at the user level.

Answer (score 0):

In android studio, Click on File and then Click "Invalidate Caches/Restart" and then confirm.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to File -> Project structure
2. Select Project
3. On the right panel change the Gradle Version

I was on 5.6.4 when this problem occurred and I downgraded it to 5.1.1. Sync the project and it should work after that.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the gradle version from project structure worked for me

1. File->Project Structure
2. Select Project from left panel
3. Now change your Gradle Version at right panel

Answer (score 0):

I found a root cause of this problem for my case under Ubuntu 16.04. Both .gradle and project directories should have proper permissions. I've created this directories by myself and that's why they had more restricted permissions. I just let Android Studio to create both this directories bu itself and everything was working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was used the same Gradle file in Module Gradle and app Gradle
module Gradle file was added with 'api'  .

Answer (score 0):

In my case, none of the previous answers worked for me. The solution was to delete the entire gradle folder (not the .gradle folder inside the project) and replaced it with a gradle folder backup, independenly where it's located in the operative system.

I had tried deleting only the cache folder but the problem persisted maybe because I was using a customized gradle folder provided from my job.

I do not recommend this solution in general but if none of the others works, then replace the complete gradle directory or reinstall could be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If this error occurs while you are trying to run an app on your mobile device via phone USB, make sure the compiled compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion are up to date, if they are, just uninstall the app in your phone and run the app again. If the error persists then go-to C:\Users\name.gradle\caches\5.6.4\javaCompile and deletes the javaCompile.lock file then runs the app again. Hope that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem by simply Cleaning the Project and then Rebuilding it.

Answer (score 0):

**A Simple Solution**

In my case just change distribution URL to latest

Go to `gradle-wrapper.properties` and change `distributionUrl` to latest

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip
```

And yet not solve this Error just do `Clean Project` `Rebuild Project` and `Restart` `Android Studio`.

Answer (score 0):

Computer froze while upgrading to Gradle 7.5.1 and I'm using `buildSrc`

In my case the corrupted lock file was inside `buildSrc/.gradle`, deleting this folder worked

Answer (score 0):

For People having trouble in React Native

1. delete `node modules`
2. delete `c\users\[myusername]\.gradle\caches\the_gradle_Version_in_your_app`
3. Delete app from mobile
4. run `yarn` or `npm install`
5. Rerun app

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't work none of above all.

1. Close the project.
2. Remove from project list
3. Re-import the project again. (If you have a whole source file of a project, you should clean previous project and extract the project again)
4. Open intellij and click open the project.
5. Select the extracted folder/ project folder.

It is done.