# After updating to Android Studio 2.3 build gradle is not able to build

Tags: android

> Error:Failed to open zip file.

Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupted (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

```
<a href="syncProject">Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</a>
<a href="syncProject">Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</a>
```

This happened yesterday. I'm not able to run any of my old project and I can't download this dependency though I have good internet connection.

Comment: See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593758/gradle-error-after-updating-to-android-studio-2-3/42603803#42603803)

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue today after updating to Android Studio 2.3.

I had to update my build tools to `25.0.0` you can do this by changing the `buildToolsVersion` and changing the compileSdkVersion to 25 in the `build.gradle` file in your main module.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    ...
}
```

Comment: true. android studio 2.3 recommends gradle 3.3 which in turn requires buildToolsVersion of at least 25

Comment: @Masquerade What error do you get for your failed build?

Comment: @AdegokeObasa here is the link-   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43097056/unable-to-build-gradle-and-create-java-class

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same error and resolve by simply doing

> Build > Clean
>
> Build > Rebuild

If it does not work, refer to the link below.

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/42609533/1358117

Answer (score 0):

Steps to solve this problem:

1) Replace Dependencies in build.gradle (project) by this code :

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'

2) Replace distributionUrl in Gradle-wrapper.properties by this code:

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip

3) Don't forget to use Gradle default wrapper in Project level setting.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem after accepting an update. I'm not sure if this is the right approach, but it solved this problem for me.

In build.gradle (Project), I replaced with the following:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
```

And in build.gradle (Module:app),

```
buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
```

After which I Synced Project with Gradle Files. Everything worked fine afterwards, hope it helps you.