# Gradle Sync Failed in Android Studio after 2.3 update

Tags: android, gradle

I just updated Android Studio to 2.3. An error is shown that one of the cache files in the Gradle folder cannot be accessed, hence the Gradle sync failed. I tried restarting Android Studio and re-downloading the Gradle files but it doesn't help. Here is a picture of the error:

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYwAE.png

Comment: Removed `.gradle` folder in your app and gradle sync again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [after updating to android studio 2.3 build gradle not able to build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42603047/after-updating-to-android-studio-2-3-build-gradle-not-able-to-build)

Comment: Clear project than Build

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your build tools to 25.0.0. Edit your build.gradle file in the main module:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    ...
}
```

If that doesn't work, I recommend you to go back to Android Studio 2.2.3:
http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/android-studio-2-2-3