# Gradle Error after updating android studio to 2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm getting the following error after updating android studio to 2.3;

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
```

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.ConfigurationInternal.getModule()Lorg/gradle/api/internal/artifacts/ModuleInternal;

I already tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42665932/5716297),without succes.

Comment: i think there is something wrong with the previous build. try remove build folder inside the app folder, then rebuild again.

Comment: Tried this, but I'm still getting the same error :/

Comment: how about try to uninstall android repository support and install it again. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38090248/could-not-resolve-all-dependencies-for-configuration-appdebugapkcopy

Comment: I uninstalled the support library and reinstalled it, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Found out that it was a setting in a gradle file from another project that I was importing.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue and then run `./gradlew app:dependencies --stacktrace` command in the terminal (note *stacktrace* option). The stacktrace was:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.ConfigurationInternal.getModule()Lorg/gradle/api/internal/artifacts/ModuleInternal;
        at org.gradle.api.plugins.AndroidMavenPlugin$8.execute(AndroidMavenPlugin.java:167)
        at org.gradle.api.plugins.AndroidMavenPlugin$8.execute(AndroidMavenPlugin.java:159)
...
```

That result pointed me to the maven plugin I'm using in the project: [com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin). After googling I found [the same issue](https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin/issues/49) on their Github and the solution is to upgrade to their latest version 1.5 which adds support of Gradle 3.0.

BTW, before all that I cleared my `.gradle` folder at home directory and relaunch Android Studio with killing java processes but still not sure if these steps were obvious.

P.S. Also, later I had to upgrade Robolectric to the latest version for my tests executing successfully. So, even if your issue isn't related to maven plugin my assumption is that you need to re-check all dependencies you are using if they work with the new Gradle version.