# Gradle version 3.3 does not support forTask() method on BuildActionExecuter

Tags: gradle, android-studio-3.0

I just updated my Android Studio to 3.0 canary 1.
Now I am working on my existing project on Android Studio 3.0 canary 1.
By default **gradle:3.0.0-alpha1** is set in my project: gradle_file. 
So I changed my gradle version to 2.2.3 and now I'm getting this error:

> Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution.
>
> Cause: The version of Gradle you are using (3.3) does not support the
>   forTasks() method on BuildActionExecuter. Support for this is
>   available in Gradle 3.5 and all later versions.

I attached my gradle file here

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Can anyone suggest how can you fix these without having to update gradle version and android plugin version? Because doing so requires a lot of other changes which we can not do because of some business constraints.

Answer (score 196, accepted):

I've just had the same issue. Fixed it by changing Gradle distributionUrl in "gradle-wrapper.properties".

Here is what I have configured:

```
#Wed Mar 22 16:13:58 BRT 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

for more details

Offical video to help migaration
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oBsbI8ICYKg

see also comment below from @TmTron

Comment: For anyone wanting to know the latest distribution, go to the directory  https://services.gradle.org/distributions. All of them are listed

Comment: Please read @I.G.Pascual comment before changing to the specific version, because you could just update the version to the newest version currently available. When this comment posted, the current release is 4.0(stable). So it is safe if you change to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.0-all.zip`

Comment: Just take care when you open a multi-module application: Android Studio may only show you one gradle-wrapper properties fiel in the Project-Android view. to make sure to change everything, use *Find in Path* (CTRL+SHIFT+F) and search for *distributionUrl*.

Comment: I also faced same issue with below error 

`Cause:
The version of Gradle you are using (3.3) does not support the forTasks() method on BuildActionExecuter. 
Support for this is available in Gradle 3.5 and all later versions.`

So i have updated gradle-wrapper.properties file for `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.5-all.zip`

Comment: Thank you for your heads-up, @TmTron, that was my problem. falico, if you don't mind, I think it would be beneficial to highlight TmTron's comment in your answer above.

Answer (score 65):

Change in the file **"gradle-wrapper.properties".**

Put this line and Sync Project-

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

This will work. For Check latest version [services.gradle.org/distributions](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/)

After changed, **Sync** Project, **Clean** and **Rebuild** project once from **Build** menu.

Comment: Check https://services.gradle.org/distributions before you changing to specific version, because you could just update the version to the latest version currently available. When this comment posted, the current release is 4.0(stable). So it is safe if you change to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/g‌​radle-4.0-all.zip`, because it is more stable than `milestone-1` version

Comment: Yes, You are right, always prefer stable version than other. But still you can use it. @HendraWD Thank for comment.

Comment: Updating Android Studio from 2.3 to 3.0, Check official guidelines from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oBsbI8ICYKg

Answer (score 28):

This happened when trying to build debug apk.

*SOLUTION:* **Update Gradle version to 3.5**

Navigate to **File -> Project Structure -> Project -> Gradle Version = 3.5**

> This works for Android Studio 3.0

[image: this is the image of the menu where you have to make the change]

Comment: This is the solution for the ones that intentionally does not want to upgrade to gradle 4.

Comment: It doesn't. It upgrades to Gradle Version 3.5, the minimum for the functionality that he wants to use.

Answer (score 14):

Please follow the below steps:

1. Open your project in android studio
2. In Android menu, open **gradle-wrapper.properties**
3. Change the distribution url line with the below line

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip

4. Thats it. Build your project now.

Screenshot is attached for more understanding.
[image]

Comment: Error:Could not create parent directory for lock file C:\Users\Kaveesh\.gradle\wrapper\dists \gradle-4.1-all\bzyivzo6n839fup2jbap0tjew\gradle-4.1-all.zip.lck

Comment: It is showing the lock issue. android studio is not able to create the directory.

Answer (score 5):

I resolved the issue by changinf distributionUrl in the following code in gradle-wrapper.properties file

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 2):

Once add these with Top level Gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha9'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**We have two way to deal with it.**

1. You can update your gradle's version from the early one to 3.5 version product;
2. Or,you can figure your gradle wrapper to 4.1 version.

All of the ways are both useful.

Answer (score 1):

Only Change the gradle URL to

"distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip"

as follow image :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Open gradle-wrapper.properties
2. Replace:

   distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip

With:

```
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

3. Now sync project

[Click here for more understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwK0O.png)

Answer (score 0):

put this code in  gradle-wrapper.properties file and it will work with you

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```