# The version of Gradle you are using (2.2.1) does not support the forTasks() method on BuildActionExecuter

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

When I build my apk its shows an error like this. Please help me.

After updating android studio 3.0.1:

> The version of Gradle you are using (2.2.1) does not support the
>   forTasks() method on BuildActionExecuter. Support for this is
>   available in Gradle 3.5 and all later

Comment: Even though if i change classpath in gradle and gradle wrapper properties . it cause again new error.so lease help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle version 3.3 does not support forTask() method on BuildActionExecuter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44206433/gradle-version-3-3-does-not-support-fortask-method-on-buildactionexecuter)

Comment: i did but again it shows same one