# Gradle 4.4 Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I've tried deleting .gradle project from the C:\Users\UserName. But it's still not fixed. I've also tried Invalidate caches/Restart but it didn't work as well. My android studio version is 3.1.4.

Comment: Did you also try to delete the `.gradle` folder from the root of your project?

Comment: Yes, I have now. That worked. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error:Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31743942/errorunexpected-lock-protocol-found-in-lock-file-expected-3-found-0)

Answer (score 6):

Ddelete the `.gradle` folder from the root of your project.

Comment: I lost almost half day searching for the solution. Thanks!