# Android Studio: Could not create service of type DefaultGeneralCompileCaches using GradleScopeCompileServices.createGeneralCompileCaches()

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I would like to ask some help regarding Android Studio. It is my first time dealing with Android app development and I don't have much experience with being a developer neither. I'm still new to this environment. Nevertheless, I find this activity fun and it served as a safe space for me to waste my time on.

This problem of mine does not relate to the code but to the IDE itself, and I have been troubled by it for the past three days. I have looked up all the questions that could be similar to mine, but not one answer have helped me.

I made a "Hello World" project (I haven't done anything yet), but every time I run it, I always encounter this problem:

```
Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not create service of type DefaultGeneralCompileCaches using GradleScopeCompileServices.createGeneralCompileCaches().

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.<129 internal calls>
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceCreationException: Could not create service of type DefaultGeneralCompileCaches using GradleScopeCompileServices.createGeneralCompileCaches().<78 internal calls>
...126 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.<20 internal calls>
...203 more

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 25s
9 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 8 up-to-date
```

Comment: Hello, everyone. If you're looking into as to how I resolved the problem, I didn't. I have moved to Kotlin instead. Idk why Java won't work but it is what it is. This question is still open for answers tho! Just in case there are others having the same issue as I. Anyway, have a jolly day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to update:

I did not find the reason as to why the error happened, however, yesterday, I have installed a DDR3L RAM (8GB; before it was DDR3 4GB), and my Java on Android Studio has begun working fine!

The reason could be the processing speed, and it just terminated if it's too slow, I guess? I could be wrong or not since it worked fine when I changed the language to Kotlin before. Idk tho. I'm not technologically-savvy.

Answer (score 4):

welcome to Android! The first rule of Android Studio is, if things start going wrong, do `Build > Clean`. If that doesn't help, `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart`. This does a bit of a spring clean

If that doesn't work (and it might not, I think I've run into it before, the issue with a lock file) there's a few things you can try, can't promise they'll work but hey:

- run Execute Gradle Task (do ctrl+shift+a and start typing) and do `gradle --stop`, try rebuilding
- find the `.gradle` data folder (on Windows it's `C:\Users\You\.gradle`, go into `daemon` and find the version of Gradle you're using (check the `gradle.wrapper.properties` file in your project). Delete the `registry.bin.lock` file
- if that doesn't work, maybe delete the `.gradle\caches` folder since your error mentions compile caches - stuff will have to redownload though

I forget what I had to do to fix it last time. [There's a thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31743942/errorunexpected-lock-protocol-found-in-lock-file-expected-3-found-0) but it's a lot of people trying different things. Generally you don't get these issues, so you got unlucky, but yeah it can be a pain sometimes. Hope you get it working!

Comment: Hello, cactustictacs. My sincerest apologies for the late reply. I was busy with school stuffs. Anyway, regarding the answers and options you provided, none of them seem to work unfortunately. I tried the gradle --stop option, but it said "Unknown command-line option '--stop'''.  Nevertheless, thank you for answering my question. While it may not have helped me, it may help others instead.