# Intellij + Gradle Could not create service of type FileHasher using BuildSessionServices.createFileHasher()

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I have imported a new Gradle project i have to start working on, my IDE is Intellij updated to the latest version `2021.2.4`

As soon as the build starts i get:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Gradle could not start your build.
> Could not create service of type FileHasher using BuildSessionServices.createFileHasher().
   > Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I have tried every single proposed solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31743942/errorunexpected-lock-protocol-found-in-lock-file-expected-3-found-0) thread (90% of them propose to delete the caches from the `.gradle` or its entire folder), but nothing worked.
Does anyone have a different solution?
My windows 10 FS yesterday night froze and after the restart this issue showed up.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue when running my Flutter project. The build failed exception was:

```
Gradle could not start your build.
> Could not create service of type FileHasher using BuildSessionServices.createFileHasher().
   > Cannot lock file hash cache (/Users/user-name/IdeaProjects/project-name/android/.gradle/7.5/fileHashes) as it has already been locked by this process.
```

I resolved this by doing the following:

1. Go to `android` folder
2. Run `./gradlew --stop`

And then, run the project.