# React native app installation fails on Andoid

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, gradlew

I just created a new react-native project and I'm getting the following error when trying to run it on android or running gradlew clean:

```
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create an instance of type org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinScriptPluginFactory.
> Could not create service of type KotlinDslWorkspaceProvider using GradleUserHomeServices.createKotlinDslWorkspaceProvider().
   > Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.
```

After trying to start an old react-native app I noticed I can't install any app at the moment, so there's probably a mistake outside my project.

Did anyone experience something like that already?

Comment: Try clean and build again?

Comment: I get the same error when running gradlew clean...

Comment: generally when it happens to me I just follow the link that is provided and check if I didn't misse anything during the setup of react native.

Comment: This should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31743942/errorunexpected-lock-protocol-found-in-lock-file-expected-3-found-0

Comment: I'm pretty sure I didn't miss anything. And as I said, my old projects wont start aswell (Last week they started as expected)

Comment: maybe you changed your jdk or something inadvertently.

Comment: @AleksandarZoric I'm now getting this error:
Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.

How do I upgrade my Java version?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by using Java 11 instead of java 8.

I deleted the gradle cashe and then got a new error telling me to use java 11.

Comment: Yeah, probably because your build.gradle file(s) is set to compile with Java 11. Glad you got it sorted it though.