# Flutter project fails to run

Tags: flutter, dart

Im trying to run the demo of flutter in android studio with a new flutter project but this happen
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 1, found 0.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 906ms
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

i already try to put --stacktrace ,.. in the command line but still doesnt work , every thing ok when i use flutter doctor -v
i expect the demo of the app pop up .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error:Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31743942/errorunexpected-lock-protocol-found-in-lock-file-expected-3-found-0)

Comment: Running with `--stacktrace` is to see the stack trace of the error, it won't fix the issue

Comment: do you have any idea how to fix these

Comment: i have also tried flutter clean

Comment: Yes, see the link above, there are many solutions

Comment: i have tried severals from that link and none work

Comment: after trying one of them now after i connect the phone simualtor , it still say no device connected

Comment: So your problem on running is solved now, the "no device connected" is another problem, you can try running the emulator manually

Comment: are you sure the running is solved , i delete the 7.5 gradle solution

Comment: seems like it not cuz when the connection back to normal , the old issue came back