# Android Studio 2.1 unexpected lock protocol

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with Android Studio 2.1

i have an error ..

```
Gradle project refresh failed
Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0
```

i already tried many things to solve my problem like

deleting my `.gradle folder`.
Invalidate `Caches/restart` .
change `gradle` setting to `default`.
close and reopen.
create a PATH name `JAVA_HOME` & `JDK_HOME` where I put the path of my `jdk`

and make my `android` studio updated .
still got the error.

Some of the question like mine .
I already did their answers . 
nothings works on me ..

Please help me solve that problem 
I really need to make it work. :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android studio unexpected lock file protocol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27481981/android-studio-unexpected-lock-file-protocol)

Comment: what do you mean duplicate?
i know many other have same problem with me .. but i read the answers .. 
nothing can solve my problem .. like you posted duplicated .
i already did that all delete folders .. but still noting happen to my android studio ..

Comment: The one in `%UserProfile%\.gradle` as well? (windows equivalent to `~/.gradle`)

Comment: yes already did that..

Answer (score 0):

(1) Go into your local file project and search for the ".gradle" folder 
(2) Erase it and restart your IDE.
OR
(3) Delete ~/.gradle/caches/2.8/ (2.8 is gradle version that used in the project)