# Android Studio is not working properly

Tags: java, android

I have installed Android Studios 1.2.1.1 and I am getting a sync error "Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality will not work". The error in console is :

`"Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3 found 0"`

I have searched online for any answers and have none. My SDK seem to be correct. Anybody have the same issues and solutions?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23196254/how-to-start-develop-application-for-fire-os-in-android-studio-ide ?

Comment: ok it says delete ~/.gradle/. Where is this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the similar message "Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality will not work" after searching online i found this and it work perfect for me.
 The fix in my case was to refer to a correct version of JDK. My Android Studio is 64-bit (on Windows you can see it in task manager as studio64.exe) while it was referring to 32-bit JDK. To check it go to File > Other Settings > Default Project Structure > JDK location and check the path. Under windows, if it shows 32-bit location C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25 instead of 64-bit path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_XX then change it to the correct one. If you don't have a 64-bit JDK then download and install it.